# How do I view cluster status in CnosDB?

Tags: database, cnosdb

I have set up the CnosDB cluster (3 meta nodes + 3 data nodes) according to the [manual](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/cluster/cluster.html).

Is there any easy way to view the cluster status in a command? I found this command doing partial work:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:21001/metrics
curl http://127.0.0.1:21002/metrics
curl http://127.0.0.1:21003/metrics
```

However I would like to see the following details: ip, role, status, version, etc.